# Guice: requesting instances, not types

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

Let's make the statement "`All Rocks have Minerals.`":

```
public class Mineral
{
    // Nevermind why a Mineral would have a GUID.
    // This is just to show that each Mineral instance
    // is universally-unique.
    String guid;

    @Inject
    public Mineral(String id)
    {
        guid = id;
    }
}

public class Rock
{
    private Mineral mineral;

    @Inject
    public Rock(Mineral min)
    {
        mineral = min;
    }
}
```

If we want 2 `Rock` instances, each of them configured with different `Mineral` instances (each with their own GUIDs):

```
public class RockModule extends AbstractModule
{
    public void configure(Binder binder)
    {
        // Make two Minerals with different GUIDs.
        Mineral M1 = new Mineral(UUID.getRandomId().toString());
        Mineral M2 = new Mineral(UUID.getRandomId().toString());

        // Configure two Rocks with these unique Minerals
        Rock R1 = new Rock(M1);
        Rock R2 = new Rock(M2);

        // Define bindings
        bind(Rock.class).toInstance(R1);

        // No way for Guice to expose R2 to the outside world!
    }
}
```

So now, when we ask Guice for a `Rock`, it will always give us the `R1` instance, which itself is configured with the `M1` instance of `Mineral`.

In Spring DI, you can define two beans to be the same type, but just give them different bean IDs. Then you "wire" beans together using their IDs. So I could wire `R1` and `M1` together, `R1` and `M2` together, etc. Then, I can ask Spring for `R1` or `R2` as I need them.

With Guice, you can only ask for the **type** you want (`Rock.class`), not the **instance**.

**How do you request different "wired beans" with Guice? By using different `AbstractModule` concretions? Or is this a limitation of Guice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this would be a violation of what Guice recommends.  You would not typically `new` up a class inside of a module to create instances because it defeats the purpose of using a DI container in the first place.  (Why then annotate your classes with `@Inject`?)

Rather, you'd let Guice do this for you:

```
class RockModule extends AbstractModule {
  public void configure() {}

  @Provides
  @Named("UUID")
  public String getUuid() {
    return UUID.getRandomId().toString();
  }
}
```

Now each `Mineral` automatically gets a unique UUID, and each `Rock` gets a unique `Mineral`.

This gets us part way, but if you want two unique pairings of a Rock and Mineral for use at runtime, then this is what Guice calls the "robot legs" problem, and you can solve it using **private modules**.  See an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want [binding annotations](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). Guice doesn't bind by *type* - it binds by *key* - but if you don't do anything else, the key will just consist of the type. Binding annotations allow you to create richer keys.

The linked documentation explains it better than I can, but the result is that there are various ways of specifying what you want, including:

```
@Inject
public Foo(@Named("X") Rock rock)
```

or

```
@Inject
public Foo(@HardRockCafe Rock rock)
```

where in the latter case, `@HardRockCafe` is a custom binding annotation.

Comment: @herpylderp: Well, it depends what you mean by "exactly" - but basically, yes.